# Year(Getdate()) taking 30 times longer to execute on SSRS starting Jan 1st, 2016

Tags: sql-server, function, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that has been running for years.  As of 1/1/2016 one part of the report is taking over 30 times longer to execute.  It turned out to be the use of the `Year(Getdate())` function in the where clause of the query.  Changed it to a declared variable `@CurrYear int = Year(Getdate())` and then used `@CurrYear` in the where clause and it is back down to less than a second.  Why would this stop working on 1/1/2016 when it had been working for years?  Just curious if anyone else has seen this behaviour.

Also, the queries run fine from management studio, the delay only happens on the report server.

Comment: you should look at the execution plan

Comment: Can you provide us the query? Is this query run within a stored procedure or directly from SSRS report?

Comment: I haven't noticed any difference when I add a YEAR function to some queries with thousands of records. You say it only happens on the Report Server but I assume you also mean the report is slow in BIDS but the query is quick. It sounds more like a rendering issue since the query itself is quick but that shouldn't be fixed by changing the YEAR function.